# What is the correct way to cache blocks by language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, caching

I have a multilingual site with custom blocks in the right-hand menu - the content of which is generated dynamically through the `build()` function of BlockBase and which changes depending on the interface language. I want to cache these once per language. Elsewhere I've used:

```
public function build() {
 $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
 return array(
  '#theme' => 'my_template',
   ....
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => [
      'node:' . $node->getId()
    ],
  ],
);
```

}

I've gone with this approach, which appears to work, although I'm not sure how to test that it isn't still processing templates on every call:

```
public function build() {
 return array(
  '#theme' => 'my_template',
   ....
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => [
      'language:' . \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId()
    ],
  ],
);
```

}

Is this the correct way to do it? I could find examples of the `node:` prefix in the docs, but nothing about `language:`

Answer (score 7):

You should use the languages context, don't use tags here.

Like this: `'#cache' => ['contexts' => ['languages:language_interface']],`

You'll find more here: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts

Comment: Correct answer, but note that the interface language is already a default cache context that is applied to anything. So it should already do that without having to specifiy anything. If it doesn't work then you have a different problem.

Comment: Thanks @Rainer - is it fine to mix `contexts` and `tags` (e.g. 'node:123') in the same `#cache` ?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The cache array is better described as the invalidate-cache-when array. That means the cache will be invalidated when one of the contexts changes or one of the tags is invalidated.

Comment: Yes, Eyal is right. And the third caching mechanism is "max-age". You may mix all three cache keys (tags, contexts, max-age). The cache is invalid if at least one of them is invalid.